# PS4 Controller needs to be synced every boot

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, hardware

So I've had a PS4 Pro for about a year now and pretty much since day 1 it's had an issue with controller connection. The Dualshock 4 can almost never be used to turn on the console.

The controller will pulse white as if it was searching, and continue doing that for about 10 seconds before I assume giving up. This is the same whether the controller is plugged in or not.

The only way to boot the console is to hard reset (with the pinhole button) and re-sync it every time I turn on the Playstation. It works great after that; I've never had the controller drop connection randomly, or have any issue communicating plugged in or wireless.

I've attempted testing for wireless interference the best I can by disabling my router but the connection issues persist. Today I finally bought a second controller and right out of the box it's having the same issue.

I've also tried booting into safe mode to rebuild the database and using a keyboard to remove the controllers from the console's Bluetooth devices then pairing manually from but both of these have had no affect.

Has anyone else had an issue like this? I've searched quite a bit and seen a lot of results of general connection issues but very few complaints about such consistent issues with syncing.

Comment: You've already done some research on the subject, but have you tried contacting Sony tech support? In my experience, it  can be a bit hit-and-miss depending on who you get on the phone, but overall I've usually been helped quite well. Also, you really should try to get this done before your warranty expires, as it might be a defect in your console. In that  case, Sony or your store will at least (try to) repair it, or even send you a new one!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly I believe I may already be out of warranty but It's probably still my best bet by this point.